# Make a google search from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a simple chrome extension which will take input from a textbox and do a google image search and show the results in the extension's window.

I've tried using a GET form but that doesn't seem to be working at all. I'm trying to get their JSAPI (from https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/?hl=en) and I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'ImageSearch' of undefined" in the console.

Google seems to want me to use their custom search engine (CSE) function but it's not a website I'm doing this from it's an extension.

Comment: I would first try just manipulating the image query url `https://www.google.com/search?q=param1+param2+param3&source=lnms&tbm=isch`

Comment: I think what @xjsc16x is looking for is an embeddable search function that she/he can customize. Not just the format to perform a regular Google Images search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the Custom Search Engine with its builder, you can use the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-devguide), which is a customizable extension of the Custom Search Engine.

Also, a Google Chrome extension is basically a webpage with access to additional APIs and functionality (especially limited control over the user's browsing experience).

---

**EDIT (Dec 22, 2020):** As of Oct 24, 2016 it seems like Google stopped supporting their Custom Search API linked above. Refer to the updated [Programmable Search Element Control API v2](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element), which functions differently but should still answer the original question.

Relevant snippet demonstrating basic usage of the new API, modified from the linked page:

```html
<!-- Put the following javascript before the closing </head> tag
and replace 123:456 with your own Programmable Search Engine ID. -->
<!-- NOTE: I've replaced "123:456" with the example ID from the documentation page -->
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=000888210889775888983:y9tkcjel090"></script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want both of the search box and the search results to render -->
<div class="gcse-search"></div>
```

Comment: I get the search box to load now but the search will not load. I believe it has something to do with the CSP? here's the error: "GET chrome-extension://www.google.com/adsense/search/async-ads.js net::ERR_FAILED" and here's my csp string: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"

Comment: Yes, it is because of the [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), but only for chrome extensions. If my answer was helpful, please upvote or mark as "accepted". Thanks!

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @ArcaEgeCengiz I've updated my answer to reference the new API. Also, both pages should be on the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/web.php) now; If you want to read the old documentation, select the snapshot before Oct 24, 2016.